# Microsoft Sync Framework on Microsoft Hosted Agent?

Tags: azure-devops

Can someone please confirm if we can install Microsoft Synchronization Framework on Microsoft Hosted Agent & whats the process to do that? We have to create a Build pipeline in Azure Devops services. Also can we install DevExpress on MS Hosted agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add software during your build or release using [tool installer tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tool-installers).

For a list of our tool installer tasks, see [Tool installer tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops#tool).

Regarding Microsoft Sync Framework, since it has been in [Nuget packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SyncFramework/), you could add the package reference below in your project, and `nuget restore` task will restore the package during pipeline.

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SyncFramework" Version="2.1.0.2" />`

Comment: HI Cece, Thanks for your response. However, I cannot see DevExpress software in Tool Installer tasks.  How can we installed licensed devexpress on MS hosted agent?

Comment: Also please advise where can we place the package reference as you stated earlier. Do we need to create nuget.config file to add this reference i.e. <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SyncFramework" Version="2.1.0.2" /> ?

Comment: Can the DevExpress software install from command line? How's your project like? It's supposed there is a `packages.config` file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config.

Comment: Hi Cece, thanks for your advice on adding the package reference for MS Sync Framework. Now, when we run the build pipeline, we are not seeing MS Sync related errors. I created the packages.config file under projects & & added the above project reference for MS Sync framework. Now, issue left is for DevExpress. Not sure how that can be achieved.

Comment: Great to see the package issue is solved. Regarding DevExpress, you need to get help from DevExpress side to see how to install this software from command line. If it doesn't support install from command line, then you have to deploy a self-hosted agent to use this software.